# Retrieve office key after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 without carrying anything over

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, microsoft-office

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. After I put all my data on an external hard disk, I wiped my computer clean: I upgraded to Windows 10 without carrying any of my leftover data from Windows 7. Nothing is left, no programs or data, and I don't have a backup of my old installation either.

Unfortunately, I was dumb enough to believe that Office was somehow connected to my Windows 7 key and that it would somehow be carried over. Nope. When it said it would delete all data, it really meant *all* data. So my old Office key, which was the Office 365 version I believe, seems to be lost.

The PC is pretty old (bought 2013 I believe) and it was pre-installed with Windows 7, and Office too, I think. So I don't have any installation discs, the only thing I have is the Windows 7 Home Premium key that is on a sticker on the side of my PC. Is it possible to get my Office license out of it somehow?

Comment: You need to ask the manufacturer if they can give you an Office key that went with your license. Without a receipt, Microsoft probably will not be able to help

Comment: If you had Ofice 365 installed then your license is connected to your Microsoft Account.  As a side note, the manufacturer of your laptop absolutely does not know what your office key was.

Comment: "Is it possible to get my Office license out of it somehow?" - To answer this question directly, if you do not actually have Office 365, but Office 2013/2016/2019, and you didn't take note of the key before you reinstalled Windows then the key is lost.  The manufacturer (OEM) of your laptop won't have that information.

Comment: Damn :( That's what I feared. Oh well, should've thought a little bit ahead.

Comment: If you really have lost all, an Office 365 subscription is reasonably priced and offers you 5 installs. If you do this, the license it held in the Microsoft licensing server.

Comment: Make and model of PC please.

Comment: @John That would sound great in theory, but I'm not really a fan of subscriptions, I'd rather buy it once and own the software.

Comment: @Moab It's a custom made PC, I'm not sure I can find that info. Apparently, it was created from a service from a local shop, where you can choose what kind of parts you want in your PC.

Comment: Subscriptions are cheaper than buying once (one copy only) . This has worked well for me for some years now. Office 2019 is now the buy once product, but it has become orphaned because development goes to Office 365

Comment: @John That's great, but I don't really use Word that often, so it's harder for me to justify shelling out money for something I might use once or twice a month at best. That's why I generally don't like subscription models.

Comment: @John - Office 2019 isn't orphaned.  Perpetual versions of Office are still a thing in the Enterprise.

Comment: @noClue -For some reason I assume the device was an laptop.  This copy of license, how did you purchase it, be as specific as possible.  If you purchased it online then an email, with the license key, was sent to you.  If it's a copy of Office 365 then that's only a subsription, If you had Office 365 Personal, then you likely have a subscription.  Check your Microsoft account/.

Comment: Try a free productivity tool, such as LibreOffice. It offers about the same functionality as MS Office, but might take a short while to get used to the interface. No fee, no subscription, no charge for updates...

Comment: It is only the word I used to reflect limited feature updating. It does not do as much as Office 365. I also read a while back that Office 2019 was the last such version

Comment: @John - People have been suggesting that Office 20XX was the last version for nearly 10 years.  Microsoft has not made such a statement.  The only recent change is with the Microsoft Home Use Program, but that is unrelated, to a complete transition to a service model for Office.  Office 2019 is a static feature set of Office 365, it receives the same security updates, that Office 365 receives, The only difference is that Ofice 2019 does not recieve new features.